# 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u2019'

Tags: python, python-3.x, encode

I'm exporting feeds from alien vault otx using `staxii` and trying to send them to `misp`. But when sending some feeds, the following error occurs:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u2019' in position 3397: Body ('’') is not valid Latin-1. Use body.encode('utf-8') if you want to send it encoded in UTF-8.
```

```
for filename in os.listdir(dest_directory):
filenameWithDir = dest_directory+filename
try:
    file_index += 1
    print("****************")
    print(dest_directory + filename)
    print(file_index)
    print("****************")
    misp_config.upload_stix(filenameWithDir, '1')
except UnicodeEncodeError:
    with open(filenameWithDir, 'r') as file:
        filedata = file.read()
        filedata = filedata.replace('вЂ', ' ').replace('вЂ™', ' ').replace('вЂњ', ' ').replace('вЂќ', ' ')\
            .replace('вЂ“', ' ').replace('вЂ”', ' ').replace('в„ў', ' ').replace('вЂ‹', ' ').replace('вЂЉ', ' ')\
            .replace('вЂЇ', ' ').replace('вЂ¦', ' ').replace('гЂЂ', ' ').replace('лЇёл¶Ѓ м •мѓЃнљЊл‹ґ м „л§ќ л°Џ лЊЂл№„', ' ')\
            .replace('пјЊ', ' ').replace('вЂў', ' ').replace('вЂ‘', ' ')

    with open(filenameWithDir, 'w') as file:
        file.write(filedata)
    file_index += 1
    print("****************")
    print(dest_directory + filename)
    print(file_index)
    print("****************")
    misp_config.upload_stix(filenameWithDir, '1')
```

I tried to replace characters that are not readable, but there are too many of them. Is it possible to delete characters by the position indicated in the error?

Comment: does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51157481/unicode-encode-error-latin-1-codec-cant-encode-character-u2019

Comment: The error shows how to do it. Use `Object.encode('utf-8')` to encode it to `utf-8`

Comment: Probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10611455/what-is-character-encoding-and-why-should-i-bother-with-it; see also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379403/problematic-questions-about-decoding-errors

Answer (score 3):

This is basically a Unicode-problem, that would happen in any unicode-aware language. Fundamentals:

- **[Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode)** is a standard that aims to define a single well known code (and name) for any writing system known.
- An **encoding** is how Unicode code points ("characters") are stored and transmitted using one or more bytes.

There are encodings that make it possible to store any random Unicode code point (e.g. [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16)) als well as encodings that permit only a *subset* of Unicode code points - e.g the [ISO 8859-1 (aka Latin-1) encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) that supports only a small superset of ASCII.

Python translates between Unicode data (`str`) and byte data (`bytearray`) using `.encode` (for str → bytearray) and `.decode` (for bytearray → str). Your code (or something that is called by your code) apparently uses `.encode('latin-1')`, but this encoding fails for the *Right Single Quotation Mark* `\u2019` as Latin-1 does not support this character.

You can use another encoding to send that character. The UTF-8 encoding is a good choice for that, but your counterpart MUST be configured to use this encoding as well, otherwise you will receive some [Mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) where the other side interprets your UTF-8 data as Latin-1 and your character `’` could show up up as `â€™`.

If you are using Windows, it is likely that your source-data was using [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) instead of Latin-1 – this encoding is quite similar and has an encoding for your *Right Single Quotation Mark*, so maybe Windows-1252 could be a better choice of encoding.

Comment: That last paragraph should probably be emphasized more. "Smart quotes" are one of the bigger (in the sense of most commonly seen) differences between latin-1 and cp1252 (a bunch of largely unused control codes in latin-1 are used for characters in cp1252). And cp1252 isn't purely a Windows thing either; "Windows-1252" is the *default* encoding for `text/` MIME types in HTML5 (yeah, I don't know why they did that), so after UTF-8, it's probably the single most commonly used character encoding on the web. The OP's source data being cp1252 is likely even if they're not personally on Windows.

Comment: Oh, and of course, the source data could just be regular data saved in any encoding that was produced by Microsoft products with smart-quotes enabled. Even if it got saved as UTF-8 or UTF-16 instead of cp1252, you'd expect to see smart quotes a lot.